# Android FragmentTransactions and Memory consideration

Tags: android

In my application I have one single activity and aaround 50 - 60 fragments that i replace with the following code

```
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(
                        R.id.main,
                        Fragment.instantiate(LoadingScreen.this,
                                "com.myapp.fragments." + fragments[0],
                                bundle)).commit();
```

Now what happens to the fragment that is been replaced ? Will Android destroy all of its contents ? Do i have to destroy the contents of the fragment myself? Secondly, i have back and forward navigation buttons in my app (Not the Android back button), does it make sense to add the Fragment to a stack myself and check for it the next time i need it ? Are they any example of this ?

Thank You.

Comment: 50 fragments in one activity?  and not used by some adapter view like ViewPager?  i think your design is somehow broken...

Comment: Its content based, that does not fit in a ViewPager. Would you think a ViewPager would be the way to go ? Can i use a View Pager and disable the swipe motion ? and programtically move to back and previous fragments ?

Comment: create more Activities,  not one Activity with hundrets Fragments...